# Material UI datepicker dates not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI v14.4 with React and the DatePicker component is not displaying the dates per the attached screenshot. There are no errors either. Any ideas what to check or try to remedy this?

Someone requested a code post, so here it is, but this is a 3rd party component so I don't really see the relevance:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/lib/date-picker/date-picker';

export default class DatePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker 
          floatingLabelText="Submission Start:"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

TIA!

[image]

Comment: you need to post code, please

Comment: Does it have anything in the rectangle if you inspect source? What happens if you turn off (or on) styles?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @G. Stoynev - that was a great suggestion! It turns out the dates were overflowing and set to `oveflow:hidden`. I unset that and:

[image]

I can manually force override the styles for now and will notify the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue but was not able to. It works fine for me.

Try updating the material-ui library to the latest version and try again. let me know if that helps.